# onClick ListView item on database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to create an  clickable listview where the data in the listview is retrieved from the database in assets folder.

The code below is what I had tried, but each of the item now has the same content.

```
      String[] from = new String[] {"shopName"};
      int[] to = new int[] { R.id.TextView1};

      dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
      try {
       dbhelper.createDataBase();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

      Cursor cs = dbhelper.getShopData();

      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
      SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, cs, from, to);

       ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);

       list.setAdapter(adapter);

       list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {           
                Intent  objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cityinfo.class);
                objIndent.putExtra("_id", id); 
                startActivity(objIndent); 

            }
        });
```

Comment: Debug and check.. is click event working for list??

Comment: Exactly what you need??

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA, i have listed the column of item from my database in ListView. Then i want by clicking on each of this item it go to other page. thanks

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: i think you are not updating id variable?

Comment: is there is any view like TextView in listitem that show the value of id?

Answer (score 0):

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {           
                    Intent  objIndent;
                     switch(position){
                      case 1:
    objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CityinfoOne.class);
  objIndent.putExtra("_id", id); 
break;
                      case 2:
    objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CityinfoTwo.class);
  objIndent.putExtra("_id", id); 
break;

    }

                    startActivity(objIndent); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {           
                    Intent  objIndent;
                    objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CityinfoOne.class);
                    objIndent.putExtra("_id", position); 
                    startActivity(objIndent); 
            }
        });
```